# How to get HockeyApp user email/id from within iOS app?

Tags: ios, authentication, hockeyapp

I have my HockeyApp users authenticating with their email address, as described [in the HockeyApp documentation](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/authenticating-users-on-ios#authentication-using-email-address).

How can I get the user's email (or ID, or name) from within the app?

There are properties which would seem to hold these values, but they appear to be write-only, and always return as `nil`: ([docs](http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/mac/3.0/Classes/BITHockeyManager.html#//api/name/setUserName:))

```
[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].userEmail
[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].userName
[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].userID
```

The header docs say to "see also" [this method](http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/3.0.0RC1/Protocols/BITHockeyManagerDelegate.html#//api/name/userEmailForHockeyManager:componentManager:):

```
 [BITHockeyManagerDelegate userEmailForHockeyManager:componentManager:]
```

But I cannot find where to get an object of type `BITHockeyBaseManager`.

Comment: Those properties are for setting data that gets attached to crash reports.  I don't think you can access the info the user used to authenticate

Comment: @dan Turns out it *is* accessible, as Lukas discovered. Very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties you mentioned above, and alternatively the delegate methods in [`BITHockeyManagerDelegate`](http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/3.8.6/Protocols/BITHockeyManagerDelegate.html#//api/name/userEmailForHockeyManager:componentManager:) are used to enrich crash reports and feedback messages with additional meta data about your user.

<s>The email address that is used during the authentication process is securely saved to the iOS keychain and normally not easily accessible by the app developer.</s>
I stand corrected: Actually, there is a public API for exactly this purpose, `[[BITHockeyManager sharedManager].authenticator publicInstallationIdentifier]`.
Also take a look at the [documentation](http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/3.8.6/Classes/BITAuthenticator.html#//api/name/publicInstallationIdentifier) or the actual [code](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-iOS/blob/dfd603a1edae278b2abd93134fc011ae7e32bec5/Classes/BITAuthenticator.m#L1002-L1012).

Example for getting user email anywhere in the app:

```
NSString *email = BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager.authenticator.publicInstallationIdentifier;
```

Note that this will return *either* the user email(`kBITAuthenticatorUserEmailKey`) or an id code (`kBITAuthenticatorIdentifierKey`) based on how you set up your authenticator. To set up using email authentication, I used `BITAuthenticatorIdentificationTypeHockeyAppEmail`. Here is the HockeyApp code in my AppDelegate:

```
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] configureWithIdentifier:@"<#App id#>" delegate:self];
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].authenticator setAuthenticationSecret:@"<#App Secret#>"];
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].authenticator setIdentificationType:BITAuthenticatorIdentificationTypeHockeyAppEmail];
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] startManager];
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].authenticator authenticateInstallation];
```

Comment: Also: If you need to *reset* the user identifier for HockeyApp, use `[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].authenticator cleanupInternalStorage];`, as documented [here](http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/3.8.2/Classes/BITAuthenticator.html#//api/name/cleanupInternalStorage).

Comment: Correct. Just be aware that the user might then be re-prompted for their authentication credentials.